# Getting the sencha list component to use the native scroller in android

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I want to get the list component in sencha touch to use the regular scroller in android.
The reason I want to do this is because the default browser scroller in android is also momentum based and it has better performance than the sencha js based scroller.

I tried to do it by setting scroll to false and overflow-y: scroll;
But it did not work and seems that there is more to it...
Has anyone done this before?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think you can do that, since sencha runs contained inside your browser, or inside a WebView (phonegap), so scrolling happens inside these containers.

Comment: I know that. I want to use the browser/webView scroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe `overflow: scroll` is a supported CSS attribute for Android devices, just as `position: fixed` wasn't until recently for both iPhone's and Androids.

The problem doesn't lie with Sencha or PhoneGap, it has to do with the way mobile browsers (like the iPhone and Android devices) render websites. HTML elements are not laid out in the same was as a normal desktop browser.

Theres a [slew of "bug" reports for this behaviour](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118), as most people don't realise it is actually by-design -- it keeps processing requirements low, and for nearly all websites, it produces a behaviour a user would expect. Its when we cross into the web application territory do people find this behaviour suddenly jarring.

Short answer; its not possible (at the time of writing).